# Automatically indenting text that wraps to the next line in Gedit

Tags: gedit

```
            I have a problem where text that wraps around to the next line is not indented so that 
it is aligned with the start of the upper line, and I end up with paragraphs of text identical to this
one.
```

Hitting return at the end of the paragraph will indent the cursor do the correct position, but this is not a good way for me to work in the long term. I use Gedit for writing LaTeX files, and I like to structure them with indentations for readability purposes, but the only way to get the paragraphs to look the way they should is to insert a few tabs at the start of each line after I've written it, which leaves large amounts of whitespace in the middle of the paragraph if I decide to go back and rewrite anything. Is there a plugin that can do this for me?

Comment: To clarify, are you just typing until the text automatically wraps to the next line, or are you hitting `Enter`/`Return` and then typing the next line?

Comment: I'm continuing to type. I know that I can indent it by hitting return, but that again leaves me with large whitespace sections if I rewrite any of it.

Comment: I would love to see a way to do this.

Comment: The only problem with this is it would need to reflow the text every time you resize the window; wordwrap is based only on the window dimensions.

Comment: Sounds like a feature request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The need for this feature has been noted at some point in the past, and it is marked as a requested plugin on the [Gedit website](http://live.gnome.org/Gedit/Plugins#requested), though I'm not sure if that means the Gedit developers will get round to doing it themselves at some point, or if it's up to the community to do it itself.

Answer (score 2):

`kate` has this features, but unfortunately it brings with it several packages, if you're not running kde already, and this is not what you asked for.

Another great editor gtk-based that has this feature is `geany`.

Just two editors I tried.

Comment: Plus one on Geany. I switched to Geany from gedit about 2 months ago and am loving it. My only complaints about Geany are, not enough color schemes to chose from and not as easy to switch between the as with gedit and the split screen option doesn't actually let you edit 2 files at once. Otherwise its brilliant and does the auto indent of paragraphs like you want.

Comment: When I'm not using vim, geany is one of my preferred editors for coding.

Comment: Kate's great, but he doesn't seem to be asking about other editors that can do what he wants done - he wants to know how to make Gedit do it. And I'd like to know that as well. Gedit is a brilliant text editor once you dig in, enable a few options, and add a few plugins.

Answer (score 1):

About 2 years ago, I made a bug report about this functionality:

[Auto-indent long lines (smart line wrapping)](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=559132)